# Magento 2 Remove paypal icon from category pages side bar

Tags: magento2, category, paypal, sidebar

want to remove paypal icon from category pages:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check which paypal method is enabled:

```
 Go to Stores -> configuration -> sales -> Payment Methods 
  -> Other paypal payment solutions -> Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution
  -> Basic Settings - PayPal Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution
  -> Adwance Settings -> Fronted Experience Settings.
```

Here select No Logo
[image]

Comment: Its working perfectly.

Comment: It works very good on 2.3.1

Comment: Or via CLI: `bin/magento config:set paypal/style/logo ''`

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a file in your theme directory like following

> app/design/frontend/[Theme_Package]/[Theme_name]/Magento_Paypal/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

And add the following code in the catalog_category_view.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="paypal.partner.right.logo" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Save the file and clear cache, Hope it will work for you.

Comment: why you need to add this configuration if Magento provide you settings in admin ? your approach is not good.

Comment: @HassanAliShahzad because the solution from accepted answer will remove logo all over e.g. checkout page and the question is to remove logo from category page. This is the perfect answer